# CREATE SEARCH PROPERTY LIST is not supported for the targeted platform Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

OK so I have a database project targeting SQL Azure Database V12
[image]

When running the sql into the exact azure database I want to target it runs in fine but via my database project I'm getting an error

[image]

The sql is

```
CREATE SEARCH PROPERTY LIST [spl_WorkersPropertyList];
```

The official documentation says this is supported...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-search-property-list-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

[image]

Anyone got any thoughts on what's going on? TIA

Comment: You should update SSDT to the newest version. If it does not help, then it is probably a bug and should be reported: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database

Comment: I've upgraded and am still getting the error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Visual Studio 2017 and have the latest version of [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017) installed. Keep Target Profile as SQL Azure Database V12 or as SQL Server 2014 and deploying with the Ignore platform compatibility option.

Comment: Any particular reason for using Webtrends wt.mc_id inside link instead of simple `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017`

Comment: I've upgraded but no joy. My database project won't currently build with Target Profile as V12. I f I change to 2016 then it will build...

Comment: Where is  Ignore platform compatibility option?

Comment: For anyone else coming and needing the compatability option, in your release sqlpackage.exe arguments you need /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=true

Comment: @Lukasz Microsoft MVP Program requested that to MVPs. I hope is not a big issue.

Comment: I am glad you found it @Simon.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo Fair enough. I was just curious.